# How can I do tag wrapping in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I would like to wrap my selected HTML content within a tag in Visual Studio Code.
How do I do that?

Comment: One of the reason I'm unable to completely move to VSCode and ditch Sublime.

Comment: @budji Its a built in feature with emmet... Pretty much anything you could want is also an extension now and if it isn't you can always make your own.

Comment: I like this question and I know and extension call (Emmet Wrap with Abbrevation), but anyone would know how to do the inverse actions. For example: write first <p>...</p> and include inside <u>**</u> with this result <p>...<u>**</u>...</p>

Comment: You press tab after typing the tag name.  E.g. "div[tab]".

Answer (score 779, accepted):

Embedded [Emmet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) could do the trick:

1. Select text (optional)
2. Open command palette (usually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)
3. Execute `Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation`
4. Enter a tag `div` (or an abbreviation `.wrapper>p`)
5. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Command can be assigned to a keybinding.

[image]

---

This thing even supports passing arguments:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+9",
    "command": "editor.emmet.action.wrapWithAbbreviation",
    "when": "editorHasSelection",
    "args": {
        "abbreviation": "span",
    },
},
```

Use it like this:

- `span.myCssClass`
- `span#myCssId`
- `b`
- `b.myCssClass`

Comment: This should be the answer, emmet is already installed in vscode

Comment: `Ctrl`+`p` is goToFile. Command palette is `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P`.

Comment: For JSX, had to add this extra step: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4962#issuecomment-323880988

Comment: With VSCode 1.35.0 (and possibly earlier) this works out the box with JSX - no need for any extra config

Comment: That Emmet function does not appear in my VSCode (Windows VSCode v 1.43.1)  What gives?

Answer (score 154):

A quick search on the Visual Studio Code marketplace: *[htmltagwrap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/bradgashler.htmltagwrap)*.

1. Launch Visual Studio Code *Quick Open* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>)
2. Paste `ext install htmltagwrap` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Select HTML
4. press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> (<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> for Mac).

Comment: You probably mean select Install at step 3.

Comment: "To use, select a chunk of code and press "Alt + W" ("Option + W" for Mac)." Simple enough! Except it's not working. I tried version 0.0.3 with VS Code 1.16.1. It *almost* works. It tries to wrap the selection in `<p></p>` tags, instead of the generic `<div></div>` which would seem more sane thing to do. What's worse is that it fails. It produces output like `<p><p>My selected text.</p>`

Comment: I tried other extensions like that. But so far I am not having any luck finding one that works. This one was closest to a working solution. I tried wrap 0.0.1 by David Taylor, and the Ctrl+i didn't work at all.

Comment: UPDATE: the extension now works correctly and addresses the above issues. No more duplicate tag, and you can now customize the tag you want to be inserted via a setting. So if you want the tag to be a `<div>` you add the following setting, `"htmltagwrap.tag": "div"`.

Comment: that is pretty poor implementation - works for single tag, it would be nice to have something similar to notepad++ html plugin where you can wrap selection by tag from your configurable tag selection

Comment: I'm using it with VS Code 1.36.0. It's a bit clunky. If I wrap text with it and quickly add an attribute, the attribute name gets added to the closing tag, yuk!  Code ends up like this:  <a name="1">My link</aname>.  The work around is to type the "<a", then wait a few seconds for it catch it's breath, then space and the attribute, it then works fine. Not good when you have a ton of html work on!  Just checked GIT and it appears nobody has touched it for the past 3 years.

Comment: This is quite good and better than the one I'm using in Atom (which I love but these little things may cause a switch). I hope this is part of the standard functions one day. I had never realized until recently how much tag wrapping I do at least in HTML.

Comment: The extension was recently updated again and it should be more graceful. Handles single and multi-selection with arbitrary tag types (e.g. HTML, custom React components, etc...)

Answer (score 93):

If you want the [Sublime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text)-like experience with wrapping, open up the keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>command ⌘</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> → *Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)*) and add the following object:

```javascript
{
    "key": "alt+w",
    "command": "editor.emmet.action.wrapWithAbbreviation",
    "when": "editorHasSelection && editorTextFocus"
}
```

Which will bind the Emmet wrap command to <kbd>option
⌥</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> when text is selected.

You can also use the UI to do this, open the Keyboard Shortcuts menu and search for "emmet wrap with abbreviation" to add the shortcut.

[image]

<sub>As I couldn't comment, I expanded on [Alex's fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155875/how-can-i-do-tag-wrapping-in-visual-studio-code/46854557#46854557).</sub>

Comment: This is how I have added shortcut:
Preferences > Keyamp Shortcuts;...
then search emmet wrap;...
click + to add your shortcut;...
:)

Comment: additionally I added &&  resourceLangId == 'html' to work only for web pages

Comment: @surpavan, nice but It can also be handy to have in other file types e.g. html template files

Comment: @AndrewLewis - yes, that is why I kept it to language id and not file extension (files.associations).

Comment: Shift+Alt+W is free for windows.

Comment: In command I had to write: editor.emmet.action.wrapWithAbbreviation instead of editor.emmet.action.wrapIndividualLinesWithAbbreviation to make it work.

Comment: @Morfidon It's worth noting that these, at least at the time of writing, are different actions and the experience in Sublime matched "Wrap Individual lines". The documentation is really vague about this now (https://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/ ) but I believe the actions have been merged. I'll check out wrapWithAbbreviation and update the answer if it has the same capability.

Answer (score 65):

1. Open Keyboard Shortcuts by typing <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> or *Code* → *Preferences* → *Keyboard Shortcuts*
2. Type `emmet wrap`
3. Click the plus sign to the left of "Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation"
4. Type <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> (use <kbd>Esc</kbd> once to clear if the wrong key(s) was chosen, for instance, a key combination already in use)
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer as of 2022, straight to the point and you get the shortcut added, thanks!

Comment: The keyboard shortcuts ***don't work*** on [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) (say, [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)) or [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows).

Comment: `Ctrl` + `K`, `Ctrtl` + `S` on Linux and Windows (tested on [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) 1.82.2).

Comment: For the second, on Linux and Windows, `Shift` + `Ctrl` + `W` and `Shift` + `Alt` + `W` aren't in use ([Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) 1.82.2) and thus are uncomplicated to use. (In contrast to `Ctrl` + `W` and  `Alt` + `W`, which *** *** ***are*** *** *** in use.)

Comment: cont' - Though it *may* be fine to use `Alt` + `W` in this context. Or not. It changes a search setting(?).

Comment: Conclusion: Using `Shift` + `Ctrl` + `W` for the keyboard shortcut (step 4) is a workable solution.

Answer (score 22):

In my opinion, there's a better answer for this using Snippets.

Create a snippet with a definition like this:

```javascript
"name_of_your_snippet": {
    "scope": "javascript,html",
    "prefix": "name_of_your_snippet",
    "body": "<${0:b}>$TM_SELECTED_TEXT</${0:b}>"
}
```

Then bind it to a key in file *keybindings.json*. E.g., like this:

```javascript
{
    "key": "alt+w",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": { "name": "name_of_your_snippet" }
}
```

I think this should give you exactly the same result as *htmltagwrap*, but without having to install an extension.

It will insert tags around selected text, defaults to the `<b>` tag, and selects the tag, so typing lets you change it.

If you want to use a different default tag, just change the `b` in the `body` property of the snippet.

Comment: This is fine but Emmet can do this and much more, such as generating nested HTML, attributes and lists. Emmet comes out of the box with VS code.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. Of course, Emmet is more complex and I can do a lot of things but for wrapping a text selection with a tag this solution is great! When you wrap, you don't have to move your eyes to the upper part of your screen/window. It happens right there, where you already were because you selected the text! It's a pretty common use case and quick solution with a low run time!

Comment: I was very excited with this however I could not make it work :/

Comment: The snippet written to file php.json has 'scope' word underlines, and tooltip is saying that 'property scope is not allowed'. Codium, version 1.60

Comment: This works great! For those that want this to work in jsx/tsx, add `javascriptreact` and `typescriptreact` to the scope.

Comment: This is fine. This is the more general solution and thus more widely applicable.

Answer (score 5):

**<kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> is the quick shortcut for this.**

Trigger built-in functionality via [Emmet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmet_(software)) like this:

1. Select your text/HTML.
2. <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>
3. In the `emmet` window opened in the command palette, type in the HTML tag and any HTML attributes you need.
4. <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Voilà

*Note: Emmet is [built into](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) most installations, but if it isn't in yours you will have to add it manually.*

*Note 2: Double check the shortcut is there at* Code > Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts *(search for "emmet wrap").*

Comment: I've not found this to be the case for 1.47.3 on Mac OS. I had to add the keybinding for Opt+w as suggested by the other answers.

Comment: Worked for me out of the box. Not sure why yours wouldn't. Perhaps you installed a plug-in that overwrote the shortcut?

Comment: In my case it was shortcut conflict with `Csv to Json` plugin.

Comment: The keyboard shortcuts ***don't work*** on [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) (say, [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)) or [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows).

Comment: For Linux and Windows: See [Adam Gonzales' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155875/how-can-i-do-tag-wrapping-in-visual-studio-code?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment136038496_55363652)

Comment: Doesn't apply for all installations.

Answer (score 4):

Many commands are already attached to simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[key]</kbd>. You can also do chorded keybinding, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.

(In case this is your first time reading about chorded keybindings: They work by not letting go of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and pressing a second key after the first.)

I have my *Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation* bound to ((<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) (<kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>)).

In Windows: menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Keyboard Shortcuts* ((<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) (<kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)) → search for *Wrap with Abbreviation* → double-click → add your combination.

Answer (score 3):

I just installed *htmltagwrap* from the extension marketplace and used <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to wrap the tags (Windows Version).

Comment: This is already covered in [hannes neukermans' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155875/how-can-i-do-tag-wrapping-in-visual-studio-code/40174366#40174366).

Answer (score 3):

There is a fast typing of the solution.

1. Open the [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) (usually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>)
2. Preferences: Open *Keyboard Shortcuts* (JSON)
3. Add this snap code

   ```javascript
   {
       "key": "ctrl+`",
       "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
       "when": "editorTextFocus",
       "args": {
           "snippet": "~~${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^([\\t]*).*$/$1/}${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^[\\t]*(.*)$/$1/}${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^([\\t]*).*$/$1/}~~"
       },
   }
   ```
4. You select any text and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

   Result:

   ```
    ~~YourText~~
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Incredible that the fastest solution still is Cut & Paste:

```
Cut selection (Ctrl+X/Cmd+X) -> Type tag -> Paste (Ctrl+V/Cmd+V)
```

One would have thought a shortcut would have been built in by now.

Comment: Best method for most use cases.

Comment: A Tab is required after typing the tag.

Comment: This didn't work ([Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) 1.82.2) on an existing installation (nothing happens when, for example, typing `div` for the tag (except for "div" being added)). Though it did work by installation on another system that had never had Visual Studio Code installed before (the exact same version, 1.82.2). In both cases, the file extension was `.html`.  ***What configuration is required for this to work?***