# How to AutoWrap Statements with Jinja tags inside html file

Tags: python, django, jinja2

is there a way to select the **statements** and wrap it with jinja tags ({% %}) inside html files?

For Example. Lets say we have long text to comment,what we usually do is select the entire text and hit **CTRL + /**, So im looking some what similar , If i have statement like, if a == b after selecting the statement hitting the shortcut i want it to be wrapped with {% if a == b %}, If its possible please let me know

Comment: Perhaps you should be tagging some IDE here? If you don't tag the IDE how would people even know which IDE you are using / want the answer for? Plus that way your question will be noticed by people skilled in those IDE's, etc.

Comment: Here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155875/how-to-do-tag-wrapping-in-vs-code