# Wrap a Tag Around Text in vscode While Typing

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

When I'm typing is vscode and I already have text that needs tags on the outside of it, how do I have it set where I go to the start of the text, type a tag and then have it automatically go to the outside of that text. Say I have `text`. I go to the start and type `<p>text` and it gives me `<p></p>text` instead of `<p>text</p>`.

Is there a setting I can change so it puts the text in the middle of the tag every time?

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155875/how-to-do-tag-wrapping-in-vs-code) but I want a way to change it when I'm just typing, not having to execute Emmet or  install htmltagwrap.

```html
<!-- text  -->
Hello world!

<!-- Does this:  -->
<p></p> Hello world!

<!-- I want:  -->
<p> Hello world! </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I try to answer your question. In your case, you may try to install Auto Close Tag extension in vscode. Thank you

Comment: He has mentioned that he doesn't want to use Tag Wraps