# Is there a way to automatically encapsulate selected content inside a tag?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm going through `<p>` tags and selecting parts of the text which I want to put inside a `<strong>` tag. But for each one I have to type `<strong>`, then VSCode automatically puts the closing `</strong>` tag immediately after it. Is there a way to place the closing tag after selected content?

for example:
 `<PTag> Press ( <strong>Right Arrow</strong> ) key to move to the next options for setting up Date </PTag>`

Comment: Do you mean `<p>` tags and `<strong>` tags, or are the pipe characters on purpose?

Comment: Sorry, used pipe characters as using the <> in the text used them as their intended use. Will update and use them as you have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do tag wrapping in VS code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155875/how-to-do-tag-wrapping-in-vs-code)

Comment: @AKX I might be wrong, but it seems to prevent me from using Emmet as I have prettier set as my defaultFormatter

Comment: Emmet isn't a formatter, it's a shorthand syntax.