# htmltagwrap command not found in vscode

Tags: html, vscode-extensions, word-wrap

While writing html code, I pressed the shortcut alt+w to use the htmlTagWrap extension.

However, the wrap function does not work with the warning message "command 'extension.htmlTagWrap' not found".

I tried to close all the extensions and turn them on again, and I tried to go to the shortcut key and check it, but there seems to be nothing wrong, so I want to find another solution.

I am using the vscode editor. If anyone knows a solution, please help.

[image]

Comment: Is it installed? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradgashler.htmltagwrap

Comment: Hope this link will be helpful : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155875/how-to-do-tag-wrapping-in-vs-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155875/how-to-do-tag-wrapping-in-vs-code)

Comment: @mplungjan yes it is installed definitely!

Comment: @AlapJoshi thanks i found an alternative...
But not being able to use the hotkey is too fatal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, so i uninstall the extension and install manualy older version - v0.0.7. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradgashler.htmltagwrap